# Is this problem/counterexample stated correctly/valid?

Tags: functions

This problem was given by the teacher as a practice exercise. Is it valid?

If $f:M \rightarrow N,$ $g:M \rightarrow P$, and $h: P\rightarrow N$ are maps with $g$ surjective and $h$ injective, show that $\mathrm{Im}(f)=P.$

If valid, how can it be proven?
If invalid, is the following counterexample valid?

**Counterexample:** Take $M=\mathbb{R}, P=\{0\}, N = \mathbb{R}.$ Define $f:x \mapsto x,$ $g:x \mapsto \{0\}$, and $h:\{0\} \mapsto x^3.$ Then $g$ is surjective, $h$ is injective, and $\mathrm{Im}(f) \neq P.$

Comment: Did you mean $g$ is $x \rightarrow \{0\}$?

Comment: @JasonKnapp Yes, thanks.

Comment: If there is no relation between $f, g$ and $h$, why would hypotheses about $g$ and $h$ allow any conclusion on $f$?

Comment: @Bernard We are not given that the diagram of $f,g,h$ commutes, but if it did, would that change anything?

Comment: @anonymous Yes, because that's another way of saying that $f = h \circ g$.

Comment: As is, your problem is meaningless: is $P$ a subset of $N$? Your teacher might as well have asked for the age of the captain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your counterexample is very close, just a bit of notation is off.

In $g$, you probably really mean $g: x \to 0$ not $g: x \to \{0\}$, because the former assigns a real number value of $0$ to all possible inputs whereas the latter assigns a value of the SET $\{0\}$ to all inputs.

Your mapping $h$ is also little funny because $x^3$ is not a member of $\mathbb{R}$, it is an expression involving an unbound variable $x$.  That sounds more technical than it is, I just mean that $x$ has no meaning in that expression!  And the same comment about the $\{0\}$ holds here.. Since $P$ is just $\{0\}$ both $h: x \to x^3$ and $h: 0 \to 0$ would work for you.